# Load multiple variables from PHP via jQuery AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

OK, i have this jQuery script using ajax to load a response from a php file, but i want to do is to load maybe two variables from the php script rather than the whole page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
 });
$("#object_area").load("test.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#object_area").load("test.php");
   },10000);
});
```

So what i want is to be able to say load variable1 from the php page into object_area, then load variable2 into object_area2 if that makes sense?

Thanks

Comment: What are these variables? I'm not following here, can you elaborate a bit more, maybe an example?

Comment: Well, this is just for concept rather than a working example, but say in my php i had: $variable1 = "John Smith"; and $variable2 = "Jack The Lad"; but i wanted to grab $variable1 and stick it in object_area and grab $variable2 and stick it in object_area2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about return your variables in [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format with [the dedicated PHP function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)  ?

(don't forget to [properly set the headers](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5882))

You could manipulate your variables more simply [with JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)